# Expectation value for the time of a photon reflection

Tags: optics, photons, time, quantum-electrodynamics

A photon is reflected by matter (by an electron in empty space). How long does the reflection take? (i.e. is there any infinitesimal time elapsing during the reflection process?), or more precisely, what is the time difference, the time retardation by the interaction compared to the light velocity in vacuum. A very approximate  number would be sufficient for the answer.

Comment: It happens until a 2-3 wavelength layer in the reflecting surface. In case of visible light the wavelength is around $10^{-7}$ m, $c=3*10^8 m/s$, thus it is around $10^{-15}$ seconds.

Comment: @Peter Horvath Thank you, very interesting! However, in fact I must correct my question: What is the approximate **time retardation** of reflection?

Comment: a question came after this one with 2 answers : [Is reflection instantaneous?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/is-reflection-instantaneous)