# Time involved in reflection

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

Consider light bouncing back and forth between two ideal front surfaced mirrors.
How long does the process of reflection (i.e., absorption and re-emission) take?

Comment: related (without answer yet): [This question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/125906/)

Comment: The electromagnetic field doesn't get absorbed (to first order) and one wouldn't describe the process with the equivalent of an atomic scattering process, either.

Comment: Good question.  But I think reflection is more like scattering (as suggested by @jim 's comment below) than absorption and re-emission.  A related issue is : where exactly does reflection take place?  The reflected wave originates a short distance below the "surface" of even a very flat mirror.  This relates to the "Skin Depth" of the material.  Also relevant is the phase change on reflection, which could be seen as a delay.  However, all these processes are far shorter than absorption and re-emission; by comparision reflection is "instantaneous".